# php webservices server client with given wsdl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i'm trying to develop a webservice from a given wsdl file.

i have written the server and client code. Please can someone help me telling if i'm in the right way?

From the client i dont understand if i receive the correct answer.

Thx
here is the server code

```
<?php
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
    class getTryPing
    {
        public $arg0;

    }

    $server=new SoapServer("WSDL/TryPingService.xml");
    $server->addFunction('getTryPing');
    $server->handle();
    function getTryPing()
    {
        $esito=new getTryPing();
        $esito ->esito= 1;
        return $esito;
    }
?>
```

the client

```
<?php
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
    $client = new SoapClient(
        dirname(__FILE__) . '/WSDL/TryPingService.xml');
        //$response = $client->getTryPing(1);
        $response = $client->getTryPing();
        var_dump($response);
?>
```

and this is the wsdl

```
<definitions name='TryPingService' targetNamespace='http://tryPing.integrazione.laitspa.it/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:tns='http://tryPing.integrazione.laitspa.it/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
 <types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace='http://tryPing.integrazione.laitspa.it/' version='1.0' xmlns:tns='http://tryPing.integrazione.laitspa.it/' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
   <xs:element name='getTryPing' type='tns:getTryPing'/>
   <xs:element name='getTryPingResponse' type='tns:getTryPingResponse'/>
   <xs:complexType name='getTryPing'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='arg0' type='tns:tryPingRequest'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='tryPingRequest'>
    <xs:sequence/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='getTryPingResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs='0' name='return' type='tns:tryPingResponse'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='tryPingResponse'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name='esito' type='xs:boolean'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </types>
 <message name='TryPingService_getTryPing'>
  <part element='tns:getTryPing' name='getTryPing'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='TryPingService_getTryPingResponse'>
  <part element='tns:getTryPingResponse' name='getTryPingResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <portType name='TryPingService'>
  <operation name='getTryPing' parameterOrder='getTryPing'>
   <input message='tns:TryPingService_getTryPing'></input>
   <output message='tns:TryPingService_getTryPingResponse'></output>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding name='TryPingServiceBinding' type='tns:TryPingService'>
  <soap:binding style='document' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
  <operation name='getTryPing'>
   <soap:operation soapAction=''/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name='TryPingService'>
  <port binding='tns:TryPingServiceBinding' name='TryPingServicePort'>
   <soap:address location='http://127.0.0.1/ReCup/server.php'/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

the response i'm having is object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }

Comment: First , can you modify your getTryPing , like return a static string and verify if the response is here or not , that stage to know if the problem in your logic function or something according to the soap call configuration

Comment: in your wsdl , modify the return type of your method

Comment: what the error you got ?

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: [26-Mar-2019 13:54:43 Europe/Belgrade] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"hello"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in D:\DATA\WWWROOT\ReCup\server.php on line 17
[26-Mar-2019 13:54:43 Europe/Belgrade] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error in D:\DATA\WWWROOT\ReCup\client.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://127.0.0....', '', 1, 0)
#1 D:\DATA\WWWROOT\ReCup\client.php(7): SoapClient->__call('getTryPing', Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in D:\DATA\WWWROOT\ReCup\client.php on line 7